# Browser not showing Internal Server Error HTML Page with status 500

Tags: node.js, redirect, nestjs

I've two components in my application. A frontend which is built on Angular and backend built using express. I'm using the Nest.js framework in the backend.

I have an `http-exception.filter.ts` file which takes care of any thrown exception. So far, I've been handling Internal Server Error in the application this way.

```
if(exception.getStatus() === 500) {
    response
        .status(500)
        .json({
            status: '500',
            code: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',
            message: 'Internal Server Error'
        });
    }
```

But, now an HTML page has been designed showing Internal Server Error message. All I need to do to render that page is to hit the URL `/ui/internal-server-error`. So, I tried to that using the code below.

```
response
    .status(500)
    .redirect('/ui/internal-server-error');
```

The page loads when a case of internal server error occurs, but the problem is I'm not getting 500 status when I'm reading the network logs in the browser. Instead, I'm getting `304 Not modified` status.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction? I want to show the error page along with status code 500 and the UI page needs to come from Frontend only as I've no access over it.

Answer (score 0):

When `redirect` is called, it sets the status, so the 500 is replaced.

From [the express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) (relevant as NestJS uses Express by default):

```
Redirects to the URL derived from the specified path, with specified status, a positive integer that corresponds to an HTTP status code . If not specified, status defaults to “302 “Found”.

res.redirect('/foo/bar')
res.redirect('http://example.com')
res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com')
res.redirect('../login')
```

Add the desired status as an argument to `redirect`.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the way of getting the page along with 500 status code.

Comment: @KartikChauhan What do you mean by "getting the page" that a redirect does not handle?

Comment: I meant how to render the page without a status code of 500.